# Using Boost Tokenizer escaped_list_separator with different parameters

Tags: c++, string, boost, tokenize

Hello i been trying to get a tokenizer to work using the boost library tokenizer class.
I found this tutorial on the boost documentation:

[http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1 _36 _0/libs/tokenizer/escaped _list _separator.htm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/tokenizer/escaped_list_separator.htm)

problem is i cant get the argument's to escaped _list _separator("","","");

but if i modify the boost/tokenizer.hpp file it work's.
but that's not and ideal solution was wondering if there's anything i am missing to get diferent arguments into the escaped _list _separator.

i want to make it split on spaces with " and ' for escaping and with no escape character inside the quoted string.

this is used for a argument parsing system in a ingame console system.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost;
    string s = "exec script1 \"script argument number one\"";
    string separator1("");//dont let quoted arguments escape themselves
    string separator2(" ");//split on spaces
    string separator3("\"\'");//let it have quoted arguments
    tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char>(separator1,separator2,separator3)> tok(s);
    for(tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char>(separator1,separator2,separator3)>::iterator beg=tok.begin(); beg!=tok.end();++beg)
    {
        cout << *beg << "\n";
    }
}
```

the error from visual studio 2005 is
error C2974: 'boost::tokenizer' : invalid template argument for 'TokenizerFunc', type expected

EDIT:
This question was awnsered by ferrucio and explained by peter thank's everybody.

Comment: Rather than editing to indicate which answer you like, please make it as your accepted answer (using the check-mark button on the left of the answer you like).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost;
    string s = "exec script1 \"script argument number one\"";
    string separator1("");//dont let quoted arguments escape themselves
    string separator2(" ");//split on spaces
    string separator3("\"\'");//let it have quoted arguments

    escaped_list_separator<char> els(separator1,separator2,separator3);
    tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char>> tok(s, els);

    for(tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char>>::iterator beg=tok.begin(); beg!=tok.end();++beg)
    {
        cout << *beg << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's this actually worked i knew it was something small :P.

Comment: it is possible to keep `"` in output, for example `exec | script1 | "script argument number one"` ?

Comment: @Ferruccio is there a good reason for not having `separator1("\\")`? That would allow one to escape a quote character inside a string.

Comment: @mgd - No, there isn't. My answer simply addressed the cause of the compilation error (the misplaced `>`). I left everything else as is.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you're declaring your tokenizer type incorrectly.

```
typedef boost::tokenizer< boost::escaped_list_separator<char> > Tokenizer;
boost::escaped_list_separator<char> Separator( '\\', ' ', '\"' );
Tokenizer tok( s, Separator );

for( Tokenizer::iterator iter = tok.begin(); iter != tok.end(); ++iter )
{ cout << *iter << "\n"; }
```

You want to make a `boost::tokenizer< boost::escaped_list_separator< char > >` typed object with a `boost::escaped_list_separator< char >` separator object as its TokenizerFunc.

Comment: Those should be single quotes in your constructor - the double quotes are for char*, not char.

Answer (score 0):

A relevant point yet not the answer for this is that if user want to output a double quote in the result, the embedded quote ("") described in the Wikipedia ([like here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)) should be replaced with a string of `(\\\")`, where `\\` means a escape char and `\"` means the quote mark. In this way, the quote mark will be displayed in the output result.
The following code snippet is an example.

```
typedef boost::escaped_list_separator<char> std_token;
typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::escaped_list_separator<char>> tokenizer;

std_token a_token( "\\", ",", "\"" );
std::string s = "\"Boost,\\\" C++ Libraries\" ";
tokenizer tok{ s, a_token };
for ( const auto &t : tok )
    std::cout << t << '\n';
```

[This is a typical output for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v9WZ.png)