# python's shlex alternative for C/C++

Tags: python, c++, shell, parsing, quotes

Simple question - is there something like python's shlex package that would allow me to simply parse/split/quote/escape shell-like quoted/backslashed strings in C or (possibly) C++?

The shlex package is just wonderful with its purpose (giving easy births to minilanguages and stuff), having similar common processing tool in C would be nice.

Link to shlex docs:
http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shlex.html

Example of what shlex does:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('abc ab\\ c  "ab\\"cd" key="\\"val\\""')
['abc', 'ab c', 'ab"cd', 'key="val"']
```

Comment: The closest you're going to get is Boost.Tokenizer.

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5534620/544721

Comment: And here might be solution for Boost Tokenizer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/541561/544721