# Boost.Tokenizer for quotation marks and parentheses

Tags: c++, boost, tokenize, boost-tokenizer

I'd like to split a string into tokens using `Boost.Tokenize`. It is required that text in quotes or parentheses is a single whole token. More specifically, I need split a line like

```
"one (two),three" four (five "six".seven ) eight(nine, ten)
```

into tokens like

```
one (two),three
four
(five "six".seven )
eight
(nine, ten)
```

or maybe

```
one (two),three
four
(
five "six".seven
)
eight
(
nine, ten
)
```

I know [the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541561/using-boost-tokenizer-escaped-list-separator-with-different-parameters) to tokenize a text in quotation marks, but I have no idea how at the same time tokenize a text in parenteses. Maybe need to implement `TokenizerFunction`.
How to split a string as I described?

Comment: This isn't simple lexical tokenisation, but _parsing_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So, do I need `Boost.Spirit` for my task?

Comment: I don't know. It may be that you need it to perform your task nicely.

Comment: Maybe it's parsing, @Lightness, but I see no reason why it couldn't still be solved with Boost.Tokenize.

Comment: @RobKennedy: I don't think it's designed for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TokenizerFunction](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/tokenizer/tokenizerfunction.htm) is a functor that has two methods, neither of which should be very difficult to implement. The first is `reset`, which is meant to reset any state the functor might have, and the other is `operator()`, which takes three parameters. The first two are iterators, and the third is the resulting token.

The algorithm below is simple. First, we skip any spaces. We expect the first non-space character to be one of three kinds. If it's a quotation mark or left parenthesis, then we search until we find the corresponding closing delimiter and return what we find as the token, taking care that quotation marks are supposed to be stripped, but parentheses, apparently, are to remain. If the first character is something else, then we search to the next delimiter and return that instead.

```
template <
  typename Iter = std::string::const_iterator,
  typename Type = std::string
  >
struct QuoteParenTokenizer
{
  void reset() { }

  bool operator()(Iter& next, Iter end, Type& tok) const
  {
    while (next != end && *next == ' ')
      ++next;
    if (next == end)
      return false; // nothing left to read

    switch (*next) {
      case '"': {
        ++next; // skip token start
        Item const quote = std::find(next, end, '"');
        if (quote == end)
          return false; // unterminated token
        tok.assign(next, quote);
        next = quote;
        ++next;
        break;
      }
      case '(': {
        Iter paren = std::find(next, end, ')');
        if (paren == end)
          return false; // unterminated token
        ++paren; // include the parenthesis
        tok.assign(next, paren);
        next = paren;
        break;
      }
      default: {
        Iter const first = next;
        while (next != end && *next != ' ' && *next != '"' && *next != '(')
          ++next;
        tok.assign(first, next);
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
};
```

You'd instantiate it as `tokenizer<QuoteParenTokenizer<> >`. If you have a different iterator type, or a different token type, you'll need to indicate them in the template parameters to both `tokenizer` *and* `QuoteParenTokenizer`.

You can get fancier if you need to handle escaped delimiter characters. Things will be trickier if you need parenthesized expressions to nest.

Beware that as of right now, the above code has not been tested.